# Query extra reservation count for each date and car type

Tags: mysql, sql

**I want to query how many cars are over booked for each date (provided a range of date) and each car type.**

[SQL Fiddle Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/947cd9/2)

The required output for date range `2019-01-01` to `2019-01-06` is following.

```
date      ,car    , available
2019-01-01,ECONOMY,-1 (cars available - reservation i.e 2 - 3 = -1)
2019-01-02,ECONOMY, 0 (cars available - reservation i.e 0 - 0 = 0)
2019-01-03,ECONOMY, 0 (cars available - reservation i.e 0 - 0 = 0)
2019-01-04,ECONOMY, 0 (cars available - reservation i.e 0 - 0 = 0)
2019-01-05,ECONOMY, 2 (cars available - reservation i.e 2 - 0 = 2)
2019-01-06,ECONOMY, 2 (cars available - reservation i.e 2 - 0 = 2)
```

**Explanation:**

For date 2019-01-01 we have two cars available and reservation count is 3 so we have over booked 1 car i.e -1

For date 2019-01-02 we have zero cars available as the two cars available are gone on date 2019-01-01 and reservation count is zero so 0-0 = 0

For date 2019-01-05 we have two cars available as the two cars gone on 2019-01-01 are available now so 2 - 0 = 2

I am using MySQL 8

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question has several parts.  First, you need to construct a list of dates.  You can do that using a recursive CTE.

Second, you want to generate all combinations of dates and cars.  Then count the number of reservations on each day, and subtract this number from the count:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date('2019-01-01') as dte
      union all
      select dte + interval 1 day
      from dates 
      where dte < '2019-01-06'
     )
select c.name, d.dte,
       ( c.cnt - count(r.id) ) as cars available
from dates d cross join
     cars c left join
     reservations r
     on c.name = r.car_type and
        d.dte >= r.date_out and
        d.dte <= r.date_in
group by c.name, d.dte, c.cnt;
```

Comment: We can not subtract the reservation count from car count as you can see in example. @gordon-linoff